# How to read the fitting result of Random Forest ? sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I mean the result, not the theory:

In linear regression, there is a formula to explain the variables and weights that contribute the final score.
In decision tree, there is a path map to explain what conditions result in the segmentation.

The only result I can read from < from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor> is by pickle.dump. But pickle is still a black-box. Although features_importance_ output explains the weight importance of each features, however, that's an indirect method. I still cannot understand how the score come from.

How read the data and explain the fitting result of Random Forest directly? 
Is there any formula or path map?

Answer (score 1):

With `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` and `dot` you can visualize the decision making process. It's a little tricky to implement but that's a way to read the fitting result. Read more [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html).

[image]